# Is it possible to create a differencing disk from Hyper-V checkpoint

Tags: hyper-v

I do have a VHDx disk with with Version 1 system and a checkpoint with a Version 2 update. Some VHDs are inheriting the Version 1 System (parent disk). Now I would like to build another VM inheriting from the Version 2 update.

When creating a differencing disk for another VM, I am only able to select the parent disk, not the checkpoint. Does this mean that I am only able to make differencing disk from the vhdx file?

In the menu
Action->New-Hard Disk... in the "Specify Name and Location" it is asking for the original disk to clone, and there is no option to select the checkpoint.

I know I can merge the checkpoint down to the parent, which is something I would rather avoid as it is breaking the disk for other machines which are using the Version 1 system.

Answer (score 0):

It is unable to create the differencing disk from Hyper-V checkpoint as it is volatile and being accessed by VM. You can create the multi level diffenencing disk by using vhd/vhdx format only thorough Hyper-V manager. If you don't want to affect the parent vhd, you can use the revert option.